# Crop uploaded image and send cropped coordinates using Cropper.js

Tags: django, django-models, python-imaging-library, cropperjs

I am new to Django and frontend technologies, trying to build a Django web application in which the user uploads a image, view the full image and crops the same image at the client side only.The server side will only receive original uncropped image and cropped coordinates(x,y,width, height) of the cropbox user selected.I have read couple of tutorials using cropper.js but I am unable to figure out what is the correct way to do this?

Currently the user can browse and upload image file which is then saved in database(filepath).

my files are as follow

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
  image = forms.ImageField()
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
class ImageModel(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ImageModel
from .forms import ImageUploadForm

def upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        p = ImageModel(image = request.FILES['image'])
        p.save()
        return render(request, 'abc.html')
else : 
    form = ImageUploadForm()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

template index.html

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p>
        {{form}}
      </p>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
</body>
```

I found this code snippet answered in this question but not able to understand how I can integrate with my existing django app.[cropper.js uploading the original images with coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943931/cropper-js-uploading-the-original-images-with-coordinates)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?